# How to step into directly my personal python function in pdb mode ignore site-packages lib code?

Tags: python, pdb

When I use pdb command `s` to step into my personal function. It will step into `lib/python3.7/site-packages/xxx/xxx.py` firstly. But I want to directly into my personal function. Is there any pdb command to meet my requirement?

Comment: How are you running pdb?

Comment: I am running a pytorch project.
Firstly , python -m pdb xxx.py.

Comment: I am running a pytorch project.
Firstly , `python -m pdb xxx.py`.
Then, 'n' to step by step
when encountering a function, I run 's' to go into it. code will step into lib/python3.7/xxx and then after  sevel 's', it will arrive the my function interior. Could we directly into my personal function ? thanks